# htaccess – rewrite everything except /upload and protect with password

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder with a "index.php" and a "upload.php".

I want to redirect every request except "/upload" to my "index.php":

1.) http://example.com/abc123 -> /index.php

2.) http://example.com/upload -> /upload.php

And i want to protect /upload with a password. So far i managed to redirect everything to my index.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

In my "index.php" i can then use

```
trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')
```

How can i add rules to redirect /upload to my "upload.php" and protect the file with a password?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is upload.php a file within the upload directory?

Comment: @PanamaJack Both my upload.php and my index.php are in the same folder  (root)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(?!/?upload).*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?upload$ upload.php [NC,L]
```

For the password protection part:

```
<FilesMatch "upload.php">
    # Change "Members Only" to whatever you want
    AuthName "Members Only"
    AuthType Basic
    # This should be a path to a .htpassword file; change it to match your system
    # You can generate a .htpassword file online in lots of places, like http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/
    AuthUserFile /home/cpanelusername/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

*(Edited based on comment from OP)*

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite working yet. I want "/upload" to be redirected to my "upload.php" and every other request to my "index.php". If i use your .htaccess and type "/upload" i'll get a 404, because it doesn't redirect me to my "upload.php". Also i want to exclude my files (css / js etc.) from this rewrite (like i did it with the RewriteConds).

Comment: I understand your question better now; when you said "every request except '/upload'", I took you literally. :) Please see my edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the password protected part works. Also "/upload" gets redirected to my "upload.php". If i type something like "/abc123" i'll get a 404 for some reason though. And for the request "/css/main.css" (my CSS file) i'll get redirected to my "index.php".

Comment: One more edit; try it with the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` line.

Comment: Sorry, still the same problem as described above.

Comment: I'm not a computer where I could test this, but I think removing all of the `[OR]`s would fix it.

Comment: Thanks, almost there. The request "/css/main.css" shows my CSS file now. But my requests like "/abc123" still won't work (404).